# MySQL Update using PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, android, mysql

Everything works fine, only the UPDATE command doesn't work:

```
$con = mysql_connect($dburl, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbtable WHERE user = '$user'");
$token = generateToken();

if (!empty($result)) {
  // check for empty result
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if (strcmp($result["pass"], $pass) == 0) {
      $client = array();
      $client["Credential"] = $token;

      mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET credential='$token'
        WHERE user='$user' && pass='$pass'", $con);
      print(json_encode($client));
    }
    else {
      $client["success"] = "0";

      print(json_encode($client));
    }
  }
  else {
    // no product found
    $client["success"] = "0";
    print(json_encode($client));
  }
}
else {
  $client["success"] = "0";
  print(json_encode($client));
}

mysql_close($con);
```

I need to update the credential token in the login. The problem ocurrs with the mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET credential='$token' WHERE user='$user' && pass='$pass'", $con);

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You have `= "0"`. Why not make them ``= 0`` as you do for the others, see if that helps at all. Since the `0` is inside double quotes it may be treated as a string and looking for a `0` instead of an integer equaling "nothing".

Comment: As `djot` stated in the answer below, this line `if (mysql_num_rows($result)  0) {` unsure whether you want to check if it equals zero, more than zero etc.? Try `if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {` or replace the `>` with `==` depending on what you wish to do with the `if` condition.

Comment: I hope $user and $pass are well sanitized values, otherwise you have some sql injection problems in that code.  For instance, if $user is `' OR 1=1`

Answer (score 2):

This (second) line is incorrect (Edited/Corrected in your question already, if peer/viewed/accepted)

```
// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result)  0) {
```

Comment: Please men, Everythings works.... the problem it's only the mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET credential='$token'
        WHERE user='$user' && pass='$pass'", $con);

Comment: Solved! The error it's the table variable $table.... the correct is $dbtables. Thanks for all!